# setPath() to add FormGroup in FormArray not work

Tags: angular, tree, formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

i built an orgChart using tree Object and FormGroup.
As you can see, i've nodes associated each one.

```
var treen = [{
 name:"name",
 cargo:"cargo",
 subordinados:[{
   name:"name 2",
   cargo:"cargo 2",
   subordinados: []
 }]
}];
```

Each "subordinados" is an FormArray.

when i use formGroup.setPath() to do add new index in "subordinados" as FormGroup type, seems it does not work. and the formGroup still the same.

follow the method i to do it:

```
    clicou( f: FormControl)
{
    const arrColaborador = new FormArray([]);

    const sub = this.builder.group({
        nome: new FormControl('teste'),
        cargo: new FormControl('teste'),
        subordinados: arrColaborador
    });

    f.patchValue({
        subordinados: [sub]
    })

    console.log(f);
}
```

how can i do that and make the formArray sting changed by the method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer following a https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

as you see, i've used `var subordinados = f.get('subordinados') as FormArray;` to get formArray and so, i use `subordinados.push()` to add a new index.

this way works with me.